# Joining two tables to match integers to get a username

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I am having trouble figuring out how I can join two tables and `SELECT` different rows from different database table.

I am wanting to add my `users` table to match the `id` with the `post_creator` and then to get the `username` from the `users` table for which ever id and post_creator numbers match.

So if my users table had an id of 10 and that was the username for Jim. If the post_creator value was 10, I am wanting Jim to be found and echoed out.

Right now this is killing the code and I do not know what I am doing wrong.

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        //added in topic title variable
        $topic_title;
//  foreach($stmt as $row) {
        //Prepared SELECT stmt to get forum posts
        $stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT forum_posts.id, forum_posts.category_id, forum_posts.topic_id, forum_posts.post_creator, forum_posts.post_content, forum_posts.post_date users.id
        FROM forum_posts LEFT JOIN users WHERE forum_posts.category_id=? AND forum_posts.topic_id=? AND forum_posts.post_creator=? AND users.id=?");
        if($stmt2===false) {
            die();
        } else {
        //var_dump($stmt2);

            $stmt2->bind_param("ii", $cid, $tid);
            $stmt2->execute();
            $stmt2->store_result();
            $stmt2->bind_result($post_id, $post_category_id, $post_topic_id, $post_creator, $post_content, $post_date);
            if (!$stmt2) {
            throw new Exception($con->error);
            }
        }
    $num_rows2 = $stmt2->num_rows;
    if($num_rows2) {
        $count2=0;
        while($stmt2->fetch()) {
        $count2++;
        $post_id;
        $post_category_id;
        $post_topic_id;
        $post_creator;
        $post_content;
         $post_date = fixDate($post_date);
        //$post_date;
            echo "<tr><td valign='top' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>
            <div style='min-height: 125px;'>".$topic_title. "Post ".$count2."<br />
            by ".$post_creator." - " .$post_date. "<hr />" . $post_content ."</div></td>
            <td width='200' valign='top' align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>User Info Here!</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan='2'><hr /></td></tr>";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables... Such as this (joins users, categories, and topics)

`SELECT 
  forum_posts.id post_id, 
  forum_posts.category_id post_category_id, 
  forum_posts.topic_id post_topic_id, 
  forum_posts.post_creator, 
  forum_posts.post_content, 
  forum_posts.post_date,
  forum_post_categories.category_name,
  forum_post_topics.topic_name,
  users.id user_id,
  users.username user_username
FROM 
  forum_posts 
LEFT JOIN 
  users 
    ON users.id = forum_posts.post_creator
RIGHT JOIN
  forum_post_categories
    ON forum_post_categories.id = forum_posts.category_id
RIGHT JOIN
  forum_post_topics
    ON forum_post_topics.id = forum_posts.topic_id
WHERE 
  forum_posts.category_id=? AND 
  forum_posts.topic_id=? AND 
  forum_posts.post_creator=? AND 
  users.id=?`

Note: this is untested.

Comment: How can I get it to look to see if the post-creator = users.id? The query I posted in here was initially to just get things out of the forum_posts database, so would it be better to do a serperate query and just look for the info I need like forum_posts.post_creator and users.id?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. This is joining usernames onto the result set - they'll always match. You do have a where clause for `users.id`... perhaps you can remove that and see what I'm talking about. You'll get something like: `13 | john_doe | 123 | 12 | 45 | 13 | some contents | 2015-07-24 | category name | topic name`

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.*,fp.*  from users u inner join forum_posts fp u.id=fp.post_creator
where  fp.category_id=? AND fp.topic_id=? AND fp.post_creator=? AND  u.id=?
```

Updated query:

```
select u.user_name,fp.post_creator from 
users u inner join forum_posts fp u.id=fp.post_creator
```

Check this updated one, which will just give you the user_name and post_creator

Comment: How can I get it to look to see if the post-creator = users.id? The query I posted in here was initially to just get things out of the forum_posts database, so would it be better to do a serperate query and just look for the info I need like forum_posts.post_creator and users.id

Comment: do you want only matching rows without any where condtions?

Comment: Possibly yes...but I still need the where statements for the cid and tid as I use that for other things in the file. so that is why I was thinking if I should do a separate query possibly? I just want to find where post_creator matches the users.id and then fine the username off of that and post it in a similar fashion as I have my code now. (While loop)

Comment: I did this to see if it would work... `$test = "SELECT u.user_name,fp.post_creator from 
users u inner join forum_posts fp u.id=fp.post_creator";
echo $test;` and this echoed...`SELECT u.user_name,fp.post_creator from users u inner join forum_posts fp u.id=fp.post_creator`

Answer (score 0):

try removing this code part

```
        if($stmt2===false) {
            die();
        } else {  }
```

Simply Do:

```
 $stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT forum_posts.id, forum_posts.category_id, forum_posts.topic_id, forum_posts.post_creator, forum_posts.post_content, forum_posts.post_date users.id
        FROM forum_posts LEFT JOIN users WHERE forum_posts.category_id=? AND forum_posts.topic_id=? AND forum_posts.post_creator=? AND users.id=?");
$stmt2->bind_param("ii", $cid, $tid);
            $stmt2->execute();
            $stmt2->store_result();
            $stmt2->bind_result($post_id, $post_category_id, $post_topic_id, $post_creator, $post_content, $post_date);
            if (!$stmt2) {
            throw new Exception($con->error);
            }
```